# Why WMS Image Repeat leaflet?

Tags: wms, mapserver, leaflet

I setup wms service using mapserver, the map file is attached . I have created index page, the code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>SOLAP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.js"></script>   
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.2&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="http://matchingnotes.com/javascripts/leaflet-google.js"></script>
    <!--
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
    -->
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        window.onload = function(){

            //var wms_server = "http://wms.magrama.es/sig/Agricultura/ComarcasAgrarias/wms.aspx";           //ESTE SIRVE
            var wms_server = "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/var/www/leaflet/maps/maps.map&mode=map";            
            var cloudmade = 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/0d35918612f4498e8b04e08e5d164dec/106484/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
            var osm = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');                                 
            var satellite = new L.Google('SATELLITE');
            var road = new L.Google('ROADMAP');
            var hybrid = new L.Google('HYBRID');
            var terrain = new L.Google('TERRAIN');

            var map = new L.Map('map', {center: new L.LatLng(3.931054, -73.82812),zoom: 4,
                layers: [osm]           
            });                 

            var colombia = new L.tileLayer.wms(wms_server, {                
                layers: 'colombia',
                format: 'image/png',
                srs:"EPSG:4326",
                transparent: true
            });

            var overlayMaps = {
                "Colombia": colombia
            };                                              

            var baseMaps = {                
                "Google RoadMap" : road,
                "Google Satellite" : satellite,
                "Google Hybrid" : hybrid,
                "Google Terrain" : terrain,
                "Cloud Made" : cloudmade,
                "OpenStreetMap": osm
            };

            map.addControl(new L.Control.Layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps),{});             



            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/0d35918612f4498e8b04e08e5d164dec/106484/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: 'SOLAP CHRISTIAM', 
                maxZoom: 18,                                
            }).addTo(map);

            //VENTANA DE POPUP DE COORDENADAS

            var popup = L.popup();

            function onMapClick(e) {
                popup
                .setLatLng(e.latlng)
                .setContent("Coordenadas: " + e.latlng.toString())
                .openOn(map);               
            }
            map.on('click', onMapClick);
        }
     </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The images are repeating as shown in the photo, I tested this web service from first and works without problems.

thanks

The map file, index.html and image output map are here

www.dapboyaca.gov.co/tools/Mapa.zip

Comment: my name is Katherine and I have a similar problem and is as follows: I am working leaflet and geoserver I create a wms service and try to see it in the browser but it shows the layer wms white image but in the log of tomcat the request to the geoserver geoserver service shown. someone who is helping me tells me that is the projection posiblemnte your tapeworms also the same problem. as solved? thank you very much

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your call to L.tilelayer.WMS(), i'm noticing that you're passing an option with a key of 'SRS'.

The leaflet docs list an option 'CRS': http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-wms-crs

You may be attempting passing in an option that doesn't exist.

That being said, you're trying to overlay a WMS in geographic unprojected 4326 against an OSM overlay, with a default projection of 3857. I don't think that Leaflet can reproject your WMS to align with the OSM basemap. So... in addition to updating the option from 'SRS' to 'CRS', you might also have to re-define your WMS service to support EPSG 3857 spherical mercator in order to overlay your data against OSM or any other standard basemaps.

See this discussion for more projection-related info: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/693

Comment: Thank cacharriar after a while and with your help, I finally found the solution, here I leave the code shown OK